# SwiftUI .dateComponents today instead of tomorrow

Tags: swift, date, swiftui

I have a function which should, depending on the selected date, format it to string. But when I check if the date is tomorrow, it says it is today. This is my code:

```
func getDateString(date: Date) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .medium
        let days = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date(), to: date).day!
        var returnString = ""
        
        switch days {
        case 0:
            returnString = "Today"

        case 1:
            returnString = "Tomorrow"

        default:
            if days < 0 {
                returnString = ""
            }
            else if days < 7 {
                returnString = "in \(days) d"
            }
            else {
                returnString = formatter.string(from: date)
            }
        }
        return returnString
    }
```

The cause for this problem could be the .dateComponents. Maybe it just checks if the date is more than 24 hours away which it isn't.
But unfortunately I do not know how to solve this.

Comment: `.dateComponents(_:from:to:)` counts the _whole number_ of the date component you specified. What `date` did you pass to this function?

Comment: Also, you seem to be somewhat reinventing `RelativeDateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
func string(from date: Date) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd" // whatever format you need

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    
    if calendar.isDateInToday(date) {
        return "Today"
    } else if calendar.isDateInYesterday(date) {
        return "Yesterday"
    } else {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293243-isdateintoday)

```
let isToday = Calendar.current.isDateInToday(date) // or if you need to check tomorrow use >>> isDateInTomorrow
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get date without time (startOfDay)

```
let date1 = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
let date2 = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: date)

let days = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2).day!
```